# How to count the number of zeros in the result and append it as a column?

Tags: postgresql

I have big query which has distinct data of results .

Is it possible to add a COUNT column which calculates the total number of ZEROS in the count and display as a column ?
Result of my big query like

```html
col_12_0_|ppi_event_id|col_1_0||col_13_0_|col_14_0_||col_17_0| 
---------|------------|-------||---------|---------||--------| 
    27981|        3249| 149056||ongoing  |true     ||       5| 
    27989|        3249| 149090||ongoing  |false    ||       4| 
    27981|        3249| 149052||ongoing  |true     ||       3| 
    27989|        3249| 149061||ongoing  |false    ||       2| 
    27981|        3249| 149096||ongoing  |true     ||       1| 
    27989|        3249| 149011||ongoing  |false    ||       0| 
    27981|        3247| 149041||ongoing  |true     ||       1| 
    27989|        3247| 149068||ongoing  |false    ||       0| 
    27981|        3248| 149047||ongoing  |true     ||       2| 
    27989|        3248| 149000||ongoing  |false    ||       1|
    27989|        3248| 149089||ongoing  |false    ||       0|
```

Expected results:
To add a `count` column with number of rows having `0` in `col_17_0`.

If I have 3 records with 0 , then the count column should display 3 in front of each column .

```html
col_12_0_|ppi_event_id|col_1_0||col_13_0_|col_14_0_|Count |col_17_0| 
---------|------------|-------||---------|---------|------|--------| 
    27981|        3249| 149056||ongoing  |true     |3     |       5| 
    27989|        3249| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       4| 
    27981|        3249| 149056||ongoing  |true     |3     |       3| 
    27989|        3249| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       2| 
    27981|        3249| 149056||ongoing  |true     |3     |       1| 
    27989|        3249| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       0| 
    27981|        3247| 149056||ongoing  |true     |3     |       1| 
    27989|        3247| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       0| 
    27981|        3248| 149056||ongoing  |true     |3     |       2| 
    27989|        3248| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       1|
    27989|        3248| 149060||ongoing  |false    |3     |       0|
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a filtered window function:

```
count(*) filter (where col_17_0 = 0) over ()
```